# How to seperate out a variable from a log

Tags: logarithms

I have:
$$20\ln(1 + r/4) = \ln(4/3)$$

I'm trying to solve for $r$. Now if it was just $\ln(r/4)$, it would be easy: $\ln(r) - \ln(4)$, but in this case with a $1 + $ in front, I'm a little confused how to get the $r$ out of there.

This is part of a larger more complex homework problem, and I'm stuck at this step.
I've tried searching the internet for this, but I only find log properties for multiplication and division.

Comment: We have $20\ln(1+r/4)=\ln((1+r/4)^{20})=4/3$. So $(1+r/4)^{20}=4/3$ and therefore $1+r/4=(4/3)^{1/20}$. (There are other ways.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks! This worked along with Andiano. Sorry for no upvote, don't have 15 rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Whoops. Yeah this answer was completely wrong. I can't delete this unfortunately, so I'll copy [André Nicolas' solution from the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/986894/how-to-seperate-out-a-variable-from-a-log#comment2020782_986894) in full here:
\begin{align*}
20\ln(1 + r/4) &= \ln(4/3) \\
\ln((1 + r/4)^{20}) &= \ln(4/3) \\
(1 + r/4)^{20} &= 4/3 \\
1 + r/4 &= (4/3)^{1/20} \\
r &= 4((4/3)^{1/20} - 1)
\end{align*}

Comment: I have to say I feel a little silly for not thinking of that. Been a while since I've done much math. Thank! Sorry for no upvote along with the answer marked, says I need 15 rep for it =(

Comment: I do not see the $\ln(1+\frac{r}{4})=\ln(\frac{5r}{4})$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Me too either